# Generating 4 times using a start and end date with carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm making a sort of free sportsbetting application for my school. People can predict scores for upcoming soccer games and get rewarded with points if they are correct.

The next step in my application is to determine when winners are being picked. I need to pick 4 winners during the whole season. I know my start date and end date of the season. I want to pick winners in following order:

- First winner  = 1/4th of competition
- Second winner = 2/4th of competition
- Third winner  = 3/4th of competition
- Fourth winner = 4/4th of competition

I want to store 4 dates in my database and add those as times for picking winners. (instead of picking 4 times manually I want to do it this way, so I don't have to worry about at what times I will be picking my new winners for the next season)

**Note: I don't want winners to be picked during the times that matches can be played. So from friday till monday 23:59 isn't allowed. Basically picking a winner at the end of a matchday.**

I was planning on using Carbon but i'm not that familiar with time calculations.

**Code**

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->updateStatus();

    $startDate = '2018-08-10';
    $endDate   = '2019-05-12';

    // need 4 times between startDate and endDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that generates four dates between the start date and end date with regular intervals.

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate = new Carbon('2018-08-10');
$endDate = new Carbon('2019-05-12');

$n = 4; // Number of dates

// difference (in days) between start date and end date divided by th number of dates 
// 5 make sure to generate dates in the range [startDate, endDate]
$diff = (int) $startDate->diffInDays($endDate) / $n - 5 ; 
$fourDate = [];
$newDate = clone $startDate;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $newDate->addDays($diff);

    switch ($newDate->dayOfWeek) {
        case 0:              //  0 (for Sunday)
            $newDate->addDays(2);
            break;
        case 1:             //  0 (for Monday)
            $newDate->addDays(1);
            break;
        case 5:             // 5 (for Friday)
            $newDate->addDays(4);
            break;
        case 6:             //  6 (for Saturday)
            $newDate->addDays(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    $fourDate[] = $newDate->toDateString();
}

echo $startDate->toDateString() . PHP_EOL;
print_r($fourDate);
echo($endDate->toDateString());
```

***Output***

```
2018-08-10
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-10-16
    [1] => 2018-12-18
    [2] => 2019-02-19
    [3] => 2019-04-23
)
2019-05-12
```

Without regular intervals

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate = new Carbon('2018-08-10');
$endDate = new Carbon('2019-05-12');

$n = 4; // Number of dates

// difference (in days) between start date and end date divided by th number of dates 
// 5 make sure to generate dates in the range [startDate, endDate]
$diff = (int) $startDate->diffInDays($endDate) / $n - 5 ; 
$fourDate = [];
$newDate = clone $startDate;

for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    $newDiff = $diff - rand(1, $diff);

    $newDate->addDays($newDiff);

    switch ($newDate->dayOfWeek) {
        case 0:              //  0 (for Sunday)
            $newDate->addDays(2);
            break;
        case 1:             //  0 (for Monday)
            $newDate->addDays(1);
            break;
        case 5:             // 5 (for Friday)
            $newDate->addDays(4);
            break;
        case 6:             //  6 (for Saturday)
            $newDate->addDays(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    $fourDate[] = $newDate->toDateString();
}

echo $startDate->toDateString() . PHP_EOL;
print_r($fourDate);
echo($endDate->toDateString());
```

***Output***

```
2018-08-10
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-09-18
    [1] => 2018-10-23
    [2] => 2018-11-06
    [3] => 2018-11-20
)
2019-05-12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this based on your description, I hope it will give you an idea on how to use Carbon:

First create Carbon objects from the given dates:

```
$start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-08-10');
$end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-05-12');

// then calculated the difference in days
// using floor to get an exact number of days instead of floating point number. 
// for example here is 275 / 4 = 68.75 so the result will be 68
$days = floor($start->diffInDays($end) / 4); 

// use copy, because Carbon is mutable, which means if you don't use copy it 
// will modify the result on the original date.
$firstQuarter = $start->copy()->addDays($days);
while($firstQuarter->isWeekend()) {
    $firstQuarter->addDay();
}

$secondQuarter = $firstQuarter->copy()->addDays($days);
// do the same check to see if it is weekend or the days that you don't want.. 
// and continue the chain the same for third and last day should be the fourth quarter.
```

Don't forget to import Carbon at the top

Let me know if it helps :)